# Python sort data every nth line?

Tags: python, sorting

I have following data

```
# Data set number 1
# 
# Number of lines 4081 
# 
# Max number of column 3 is 5  
# Blahblah
# The explanation about each rows
 3842 1 1 3843 0         0.873         0.922         0.000         0.317
 3843 2 2 3842 3844 0         0.873         0.873         1.747         2.000        -0.614
 3844 1 1 3843 0         0.873         0.922         0.000         0.312
......
2191 3 2 2117 2120 0         0.925         0.934         1.878         2.000        -0.750
# Data set number 2 
# 
# Number of lines 4081 
# 
# Max number of column 3 is 5  
# Blahblah
# The explanation about each rows
 3842 1 1 3843 0         0.873         0.922         0.000         0.317
 3843 2 2 3842 3844 0         0.873         0.873         1.747         2.000        -0.614
```

My data have 2010 dataset of repeating format, which made up of 7 header lines + 4081 data lines. How can I sort the data lines, not whole but inside repeating data set? So, I hope to sort every 8~4081th line of each data set.

ps) I hope to sort the data w.r.t first column, I mean, the column-wise sorting. So, the first column of the data should be ordered, and other columns follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy to split dataset into data blocks:

```
import numpy as np
full = [line for line in open("foo4",'r').readlines() if not line.startswith("#")]
datablocks = np.split(np.array(full), len(full)/4081)
for block in datablocks:
    #lines is a dataset, sorted by first column
    lines = sorted(block, key= lambda line : int(line.split()[0]))
    print lines
```

Comment: Thank you. I have additional quesion. How can I read each column and line per datablcok? Also, how can I read only integers from that data as well? I hope to indexing each elements per line per column, for each datablock, using only integers

Comment: I tried to use command like "column1 = lines.split()[0]" but it says list object has no attribute split. But commands like "print lines[0].split()[3]" works. I can't understand.

Answer (score 1):

You know that the header is 7 lines, so you can just ignore that:

```
data_txt='''\
# Data set number 1
# 
# Number of lines 4081 
# 
# Max number of column 3 is 5  
# Blahblah
# The explanation about each rows
 3842 1 1 3843 0         0.873         0.922         0.000         0.317
 3843 2 2 3842 3844 0         0.873         0.873         1.747         2.000        -0.614
 3844 1 1 3843 0         0.873         0.922         0.000         0.312'''

data_lines=data_txt.splitlines()
data=[map(float,line.split()) for line in data_lines[7:]]

print data
# [[3842.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3843.0, 0.0, 0.873, 0.922, 0.0, 0.317], [3843.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3842.0, 3844.0, 0.0, 0.873, 0.873, 1.747, 2.0, -0.614], [3844.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3843.0, 0.0, 0.873, 0.922, 0.0, 0.312]]
```

Then if you want to sort the lists by the first element:

```
data=sorted(data, key=lambda l: l[0])
print data
# [[3842.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3843.0, 0.0, 0.873, 0.922, 0.0, 0.317], [3843.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3842.0, 3844.0, 0.0, 0.873, 0.873, 1.747, 2.0, -0.614], [3844.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3843.0, 0.0, 0.873, 0.922, 0.0, 0.312]]
```

If you want to leave the first element alone but sort the rest of each list:

```
data=[[e[0]]+sorted(e[1:]) for e in data]
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks. I just missed to mention, but I hope to sort all data w.r.t first column. So I hope to make data rearrange by first column number's order

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
f_in = open('input', 'r')
f_out = open('output', 'w')

while True:
    hdr = []
    for i in xrange(7):
        hdr.append(f_in.readline())
    # Detect end-of-file condition
    if not hdr[0]:
        break

    data = []
    for i in xrange(4081):
        data.append(f_in.readline())
    data.sort()
    f_out.writelines(hdr)
    f_out.writelines(data)

f_in.close()
f_out.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, the sorted data was bit strange, it sorted in 1, 10, 100, 1000 order. And I forgot to mention but at the last line of eacg data set (every 4089th line of each dataset), there is a '#'. How can I also include that single '#'? Thanks anyway

Comment: First part: you're sorting variable-length numbers as strings. Use a `key` argument when sorting. Second part: if `#` should always be at the end, add a third section to read trailer lines.

Comment: Key argument? I couldn' get your explanation (I'm still amateur in python sorry). Could you give me a hint?

Comment: The `sort` method takes an optional `key` argument which affects the way things are sorted. Check the manual.